# Mac OS Cocoa application to stress the CPU

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am trying to build an UI application having 2 buttons, Start and Stop.

Clicking the Start button should run the terminal command:

```
yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null &
```

The Stop button should run:

```
killall yes
```

I am also wondering if the app could be run on every mac OS.

---

My code

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {

    }

    @IBAction func StartStress(_ sender: NSButton) {

        let path = "/varun-kaddichha$/Desktop/MacStressTest/stress.sh"
        let arguments = ["/varun-kaddichha$/Desktop/MacStressTest/stress.sh"]
        sender.isEnabled = false
        let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
        task.waitUntilExit()
        sender.isEnabled = true
    }

}
```

My bash file

```
#! /bin/bash

do shell script "yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & yes > /dev/null & "
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to spin up a single CPU core to 100%, while keeping your UI responsive, you'd be much better off using libdispatch to run an infinite while loop on a background thread, like the following snippet:

```
var stressWork: DispatchWorkItem?

@IBAction func startStress(_ sender: Any?) {
    stressWork = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
        while self.stressWork?.isCancelled == false {}
    })
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: stressWork!)
}

@IBAction func stopStress(_ sender: Any?) {
    self.stressWork?.cancel()
}
```

Using NSTask to run a shell script will be difficult to deploy. You'd have to make sure you distribute the script, and you'll face sandboxing-related challenges.